# not able to load the image and pass it to preprocessing for the model prediction

Tags: streamlit

I am trying to upload the image from the local system within the same directory. Post uploading, when I am passing through open cv split and merge for b,g, and r colors, i get the error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)

### Error :

this is the error that is showing is there any possibility to debug in the streamlit where I can track changes at different lines of code? (As in the image path,) when executed in a google collab as individual ipynb files run properly and I get by required classification

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\ADARSH\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 564, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\ADARSH\streamlit\deploy_test.py", line 76, in <module>
    main()
File "C:\Users\ADARSH\streamlit\deploy_test.py", line 68, in main
    mask = imageToTensor('image')
File "C:\Users\ADARSH\streamlit\deploy_test.py", line 44, in imageToTensor
    b,g,r = cv2.split(bgr_img)
```

### My entire streamlit app code

```py
from pathlib import Path
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import random
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

import streamlit as st

from PIL import Image as impo



from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *
from torchvision.models import *




class MyImageItemList(ImageList):
    def open(self, fn:PathOrStr)->Image:
        img = readCroppedImage(fn.replace('/./','').replace('//','/'))
        # This ndarray image has to be converted to tensor before passing on as fastai Image, we can use pil2tensor
        return vision.Image(px=pil2tensor(img, np.float32))
    

def read_image(name):
    image = st.file_uploader("Upload an "+ name, type=["png", "jpg", "jpeg",'tif'])
    if image is not None:
        im = impo.open(image)
        im.filename = image.name
    return image


def imageToTensor(image):
    sz = 68
    bgr_img = cv2.imread(image)
    b,g,r = cv2.split(bgr_img)
    rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])
    # crop to center to the correct size and convert from 0-255 range to 0-1 range
    H,W,C = rgb_img.shape
    rgb_img = rgb_img[(H-sz)//2:(sz +(H-sz)//2),(H-sz)//2:(sz +(H-sz)//2),:] / 256
    return vision.Image(px=pil2tensor(rgb_img, np.float32))


def learn_infernce():
     return load_learner('./')


def get_prediction(image):
        if st.button('Classify'):
            pred, pred_idx, probs = learn_inference.predict(image)
            classes = ['negative', 'tumor']
            st.write(f'Prediction: {pred}; Probability: {probs[pred_idx]:.04f}')
        else: 
            st.write(f'Click the button to classify') 


def main():
    st.set_page_config(page_title='Cancer detection', page_icon=None, layout='centered', initial_sidebar_state='auto')
    image = read_image('image')
    mask = imageToTensor('image')
    if mask is not None:
        get_prediction('mask')
        
        
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please add the error message as text, so that people can google for it in the future. ````bgr_img = cv2.imread(image)````, looks like that comes back empty. Check the path, name and that it exists (pretty sure you'll need the file extension, too) and check for empty before passing it to ````split()````.

Comment: Sidenote: If all you want to do is convert BGR->RGB, use ````imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(imgBGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)````

Comment: hi nick, I assume you are right the image uploaded from the stream lit is not being passed to cv2.imread, any possible alternatives that I can look into how do I pass the file

Comment: I don't know streamlit or what it does, don't know if i can be of much help there unfortunatley.  ````cv.imread()```` expects a path to  an image *file* on disk in a common format (the ones you list in file_uploader() look fine). Is that what you need ? You check for im.filename in read_image(), but you don't pass it on to imageToTensor(), using a constant as path there instead. Is that right ?

Comment: Thanks for your response, yeah, streamlit is majorly a tool that can be used for the consumption layer of the ml model ,
 yes, I am aware that cv.imread() takes the path or the file name file_uploder( ) is an inbuilt function of the stramlit.
and yeah, you are correct once the image is uploaded, i am looking for a function in streamlit where I can take the path of the uploaded image so I can pass it to my imagetotensor()

Comment: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.file_uploader says: "file_uploader returns [..] an UploadedFile object. [..] The UploadedFile class is a subclass of BytesIO, and therefore it is 'file-like'." This is not a file on disk (anymore), but an object somewhere in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main function you are passing 'str' instead of variables, and also I think your `read_image` is not well structured.

What you should do is to first save the uploaded file in a directory and fetch the file from that directory and pass it to `imageToTensor()` as a parameter. That's one work around which will give you a total control over the file. Otherwise you will get other error messages after the first error is fixed.

You can automate some few lines of code in a separate python file to delete the uploaded file from the directory with a given duration.

**Note:** Keep an eye on the imports because I skipped them to keep the code short

```py
class MyImageItemList(ImageList):
    def open(self, fn:PathOrStr)->Image:
        img = readCroppedImage(fn.replace('/./','').replace('//','/'))
        # This ndarray image has to be converted to tensor before passing on as fastai Image, we can use pil2tensor
        return vision.Image(px=pil2tensor(img, np.float32))
        
    
# Refactured read_image()
def get_uploaded_image():
    upload = st.file_uploader("Upload an image", type=["png", "jpg", "jpeg",'tif'])
    
    if upload is not None:
        st.write(upload.name)
        
        # Create a directory and save the image file before proceeding. 
        file_path = os.path.join("data/uploadedImages/", upload.name)
        with open(file_path, "wb") as user_file:
            user_file.write(upload.getbuffer())

        return file_path # fixed indentation


def imageToTensor(image):
    sz = 68
    bgr_img = cv2.imread(image)
    b,g,r = cv2.split(bgr_img)
    rgb_img = cv2.merge([r,g,b])
    
    # crop to center to the correct size and convert from 0-255 range to 0-1 range
    H,W,C = rgb_img.shape
    rgb_img = rgb_img[(H-sz)//2:(sz +(H-sz)//2),(H-sz)//2:(sz +(H-sz)//2),:] / 256
    
    return vision.Image(px=pil2tensor(rgb_img, np.float32))


def learn_infernce():
    return load_learner('./')


def get_prediction(image):
    
    if st.button('Classify'):
        pred, pred_idx, probs = learn_inference.predict(image)
        classes = ['negative', 'tumor']
        st.write(f'Prediction: {pred}; Probability: {probs[pred_idx]:.04f}')
    else: 
        st.write(f'Click the button to classify') 


def main():
    st.set_page_config(page_title='Cancer detection', page_icon=None, layout='centered', initial_sidebar_state='auto')
    
    # Holds the saved file path
    user_image = get_uploaded_image()
    
    if user_image is not None:
        # Pass the path to imageToTensor() as a parameter.           
        mask = imageToTensor(user_image)
        get_prediction(mask)
            
        
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the edit, as I mentioned the problem is still with imageToTensor(), in the cv2.imread is not taking the uploaded file from the local file system. as in the file from the function read_image()

Comment: After the fix what error do you get?

Comment: Still the same error as mentioned above

Comment: In your `def read_image():` , `return image` should be in the `if` statement. I just fixed the indentation. You can take a look at it again.

Comment: That still didn't work, it gives me the same error, but thanks, I haven't thought of that before. And a quick question read_image() returns an image right or the path of the image?

Comment: What exactly do you want it to return?, With what you have it will return the image file.

Comment: If you are looking to return the processed/opened image then you change `return image` to `return im` in your `read_image()`

Comment: Since the image is returned, passing it to the function imageToTensor() should not be a problem. Is there any way I can use it to debug whether each step returns some array in the function? In if I do a print("bgr_image"), I don't see the value neither in my terminal or in the streamlit app that is running on the local instance

Comment: Of course if `print("brg_image")`  you are just printing the string `brg_image` to console. `print(brg_image)` instead. **Note:** don't expect an output on streamlit when you are using `print`.

Comment: pass `mask = imageToTensor(image)` to the `if` statement in your `def main()` it should fix the error.

Comment: Hi @AdarshVulli I just made some changes to the code. You can check it out to see if that helps.

Comment: Hi @Jamiu Shaibu, yes, apparently, even I found that streamlit has no open-to-return path for the file. I can either go with the method you mentioned or can simply use the pil save to save the image as discussed here in the forum I just seen it

https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/file-uploader-file-to-opencv-imread/8479/5

but thanks for the solution

Comment: You are welcome @AdarshVulli and I am glad it finally worked out.